# Can I conclude that $f(i) = f(j)$ given two conditions and $i=j$?

Tags: functions

Is this always true in general for functions (or maybe some set of functions)?
If $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, $g: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and
$i>j \implies f(i) > g(j);$
$i<j \implies f(i) < g(j)$,
does this imply
if $i=j$, then $f(i) = g(j) = g(i)$ for some sort of set of functions? (I suppose continuity is a necessity here).

(Question was motivated from a finance question with sinking funds and repayments).

Comment: Your second condition is still redundant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your two conditions are redundant, because the second follows from the first:

- Just to make it more readable, the first condition is equivalent to $$\forall x,y: x>y \implies f(x)>f(y)$$
- If $i < j$, then $j>i$.
- Set $x=j$ and $y=i$.
- Therefore, $x>y$.
- Therefore, from the first condition, we know that $f(x)>f(y)$
- Therefore, since $x=j$ and $y=i$, we know that $f(j)>f(i)$
- $f(j)>f(i)$ is equivalent to $f(i)<f(j)$

---

Second of all, yes, the answer is you *can* conclude that if $f(i)=f(j)$, then $i=j$. This is because $i\neq j$ leads to a contradiction:

- Assume $i\neq j$,
- then $i<j$ or $i>j$. Without loss of generality, we can say $i<j$ (otherwise, set $i'=j$ and $j'=i$ and we have $i'<j'$
- Then, from condition $1$, you know that $f(i)<f(j)$
- $f(i)=f(j)$ cannot be true since $f(i)=f(j)$.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I realised that my question was a different one (it has another function $g$), which I'll edit in

Answer (score 1):

If f is a function, then, by definition, i=j implies f(i)=f(j).

Nothing else is needed.

Comment: Sorry, I realised I should have another function $g$ in the OP with I will edit in

Answer (score 1):

For $x\lt z$, consider any $y$ in-between, i.e. $x\lt y\lt z$, so that $f(x)\lt g(y)\lt f(z)$, i.e. $f$ is strictly increasing. Similarly, $g$ is strictly increasing.

Consider a point $x_0$ at which $f$ is continuous. When a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of real numbers is decreasing to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is decreasing to $f(x_0)$ by continuity and monotonicity. While $x_0\lt x_n$, we also have $g(x_0)\lt f(x_n)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. This gives that $g(x_0)\le f(x_0)$. Similarly, consider a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ increasing to $x_0$ and we see that $f(x_0)\le g(x_0)$. Hence, $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$. This property holds for continuities of $g$ as well.

By imposing that at least one of $f$ and $g$ is continuous, we have $f(x)=g(x)$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$.

If continuity is not imposed, there is a counter-example. Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+1 &\text{if $x\ge 0$}\\
x-1 &\text{if $x\lt 0$}\\
\end{cases}$$
and
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
x+1 &\text{if $x\gt 0$}\\
x-1 &\text{if $x\le 0$}\\
\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall\:i,j: i>j \implies f(i) > g(j)\tag1$$
$$\forall\:i,j:  i<j \implies f(i) < g(j)\tag2$$

Bypassing the redundancy, if you simply suppose that $i\neq j,\: f(i)=g(j)$, there are two cases here we need to handle:

- $i>j,\text{ and (1)}\implies \underbrace{f(i) > g(j)}_{\text{false, by condradiction}} $
- $i<j,\text{ and (2)}\implies \underbrace{f(i)<f(j)}_{\text{false, by condradiction}}$

Therefore, $\forall\:i,j:\:f(i) = g(j),\:\:i=j$. By definition, a function always  returns the same result for the same parameters, so $g(j) = g(i)$. Thus:

$$i=j\implies f(i) = g(j) = g(i),\:\:\forall\:i,j$$